# Conditional Expectation Probability

Tags: probability

Walking in the street for 10 minutes, the number of people you cross has a
Poisson distribution with mean  λ. Suppose that each has a cold with probability p. During
those 10 minutes, what is the expected number of walkers you cross who have a cold?

Attempt:
Let X~Poi(λ) where x= # of people you cross and y=# of people with cold

Find E[X|Y]= sum from n to infinite of x f(x, y) / p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continue with your notation $X \sim \operatorname{Poi}(\lambda)$.

**Intuitive Answer:** Note that on average you will enocounter $1/\lambda$ people in $10$ minutes (since $\Bbb{E}[X] = 1/\lambda$). Each of those you encounter has a cold with probability $p$. So, intuitively we should believe that the expected number you encounter with a cold is $(1/\lambda)p = p/\lambda$.

**More Rigorous Argument:** Let $Y$ be the number of people you encounter in $10$ minutes who have colds. Then, let's figure out $\Bbb{E}[Y|X]$. By the setup of the problem, given the event $X = n$, then $Y$ is a $\operatorname{Bin}(n,p)$ (why!?). Therefore $$\Bbb{E}[Y\mid X=n] = \Bbb{E}[\operatorname{Bin}(n,p)] = np$$
Hence $\Bbb{E}[Y\mid X] = Xp$ (why!?). Finally, since $\Bbb{E}[Y] = \Bbb{E}\big[\Bbb{E}[Y\mid X]\big]$ (why?!) you find
$$
\Bbb{E}[Y] = \Bbb{E}\big[\Bbb{E}[Y\mid X]\big] = \Bbb{E}[Xp] = p \Bbb{E}[X] = p(1/\lambda) = p/\lambda.
$$

So, once you fill in the details of the rigorous argument, your intuition should match the mathematics set up for this situation.